# Is this graph edge-connected?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, coloring

I would like to know the following: is the following graph still connected even if every edges of two specific colors are eliminated, and is this true no matter how these two colors are chosen? If this graph doesn't satisfy the above condition, would you have some advice to make this graph to satisfy it?

[image]
The above graph has seven colors. If this graph doesn't satisfy the above condition, I think the graph with eight colors which my friend constructed will be the best graph which we can have. Yet I wanted to try a graph with seven colors. 
Do you know any way to check this sort of edge-connectivity fast?

Comment: I suspect checking programmatically would be the fastest approach?

Comment: Yes, that must be the best approach. Yet, as embarrassing as this is to say, I failed it due to my incompetence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the long dark blue edge on the left. 
Let's check if its end points are always connected: To avoid connection one of the forbidden colours must be dark blue and the other must be light blue or light green (path throuigh the bottom left). For both cases you easily find an explicit path.

Now check the lower left vertex. It suffices to show that it is connected to either of the two vertices we just considered (as they are always connected). Therefore we need only consider the case that light blue and light green are forbidden. You easily find a path for this case.

You can continue along this line of thought: To disconnect the lower right vertex, you need to forbid red and either dark blue or black, but then it is connected to the top vertex. 
To disconnect the other vertex at the bottom, you'd now need to forbid black and dark blue and then can easily find a path to the left, for example. Similarly, for the remaining vertex on the perimeter, you'd need to forbid yellow and light blue and again find a path to "known territory".

Once you have such a firm base, it becomes more and more easy to extend vertex by vertex until you have checked the condition for the complete graph.

Comment: Your idea helped me not only solving this question but also any question about edge-connectivity with colors. Thanks a lot!